# Adjust space below figure in a custom document style

Tags: spacing, floats, captions

In my two column LaTeX document, which uses [a custom document class](http://pastebin.com/K5QcEXr6), I want to decrease the spacing that occurs between a figure's caption and the following text. An example of what happens can be seen here:

[image: in this PDF Preview].

My thanks for any pointers on how to decrease the lost space.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't seem to reproduce your problem: [PDF image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt70T.png) and [source](http://pastebin.com/Z886zhfQ).  Could you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?  (I imagined it has something to do with the section coming right after, but adding one did not make the spacing as drastic as seen in your image.)

Comment: Oh, and welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I really, *really* would be cautious in using this solution, and would ask whoever gave you your class file if it's okay to do *first*.**  Most publishers get a little... upset when you make redefinitions like this.  Again, an MWE would really help pin down the actual problem.

A dirty trick (and one probably not allowed by your publisher) is to redefine the captioning.

Note that this will *most likely* break other spacing throughout your article, so even if it *is* allowed, I would be careful about using it.

If you feel comfortable editing the document class (probably not a good idea, since your publisher will have their own 'more definitive copy'), you can just make the necessary edit; otherwise add the following to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{\par\addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}{%
   \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}
   \begingroup \@parboxrestore \normalsize
     \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}{#1}\par
     \vspace{-2ex} %%% Change this to your liking
   \endgroup}
\makeatother
```

Making the change drastic (`3cm`) produced the following on my end:

[image]

so it definitely decreases the space there.

Comment: Another, equivalently hack-y solution would be to add each `\vspace` as appropriate after each figure.

Comment: Thanks Sean, a \vspace does the trick. Thanks for explaining how to do it both in preamble and every figure. Since it's only a two page document will go with the per-figure hack.